# Bootstrap carousel, white space on right side

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I'm making a website as a job application and have encountered a pretty annoying problem with some unwanted whitespace, in mobile view, at the right side of my carousel.

I think I have edited every single element I can think off, but still no luck. Would love to get some help on this.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkolaas/2rfr8a8f/)

```
Code in fiddle
```

[Link to live site](http://www.robertkolaas.no/fjuz)

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Please include your code! We have no idea what we're looking at here. If you provide a [MCVE] of your problem (the more minimal the better!) I'm sure you'll get a rapid response, but your question now is so vague that there's no way to tell what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your css something like this:

```css
.row.carousel-inner {
    margin: 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

If it does not work try this:

```css
.row {
    margin: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesnt fix the issue, sadly.

Comment: @RobertKolås Try now

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please add these styles with media query only for mobile

```
.carousel-inner {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.item {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this: 
 `<div class="carousel-inner" style"margin= auto ">` 
this will make the right and left margins resize automatically equally.

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap `3.3.7` I used:

```
<div class="row container-fluid">
```

This solved the problem and aligned the Carousel element to the middle of the page (Upper level container).